# How to integrate the following integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I need to integrate the following integral $$\int \frac{1}{x}e^{ax^2+bx}e^{-cx^{m}}\sin(ex^m)dx$$ where $a,b,c,e$ are positive real values and $0<m<1$. Any help or direction to solve this integral will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very confusing to have $d$ in the integrand...

Comment: Judging by the amount of transcendental functions in the integrand, I don't think the definite integral can be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician ok what if we assume $d=1$. Will it make it more tractable?

Comment: Not what I was talking about. More explicitly: people use differentials a lot within functions, so I would suggest using a different letter instead of $d$ for that parameter. Other than that: this doesn't look like it has a simple closed form except for special cases of the parameters.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician is it possible to get some good looking expression for $m=.5$? or for any other special case?